# How many USB-C monitors can I connect to a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I would like to connect at least two USB-C monitors, but maybe 3 if possible.

Firstly, should it work? Secondly, will it work well in terms of performance? I mostly need the monitors for text editing and web browsing (not video editing or gaming).